# Eliminating code duplication between similar sum type methods

Tags: haskell

## Question

I'm implementing Scheme, and part of my numerical tower looks something like this:

```
data MyNumber
  = MyInt Integer
  | MyFloat Float

instance Num MyNumber where
  abs = \case
    MyInt val -> MyInt $ abs val
    MyFloat val -> MyFloat $ abs val

  signum = \case
    MyInt val -> MyInt $ signum val
    MyFloat val -> MyFloat $ signum val

  negate = \case
    MyInt val -> MyInt $ negate val
    MyFloat val -> MyFloat $ negate val

  (+) a b = case (a, b) of
    (MyInt a', MyInt b')     -> MyInt $ a' + b'
    (MyInt a', MyFloat b')   -> MyFloat $ fromInteger a' + b'
    (MyFloat a', MyInt b')   -> MyFloat $ a' + fromInteger b'
    (MyFloat a', MyFloat b') -> MyFloat $ a' + b'

  (*) a b = case (a, b) of
    (MyInt a', MyInt b')     -> MyInt $ a' * b'
    (MyInt a', MyFloat b')   -> MyFloat $ fromInteger a' * b'
    (MyFloat a', MyInt b')   -> MyFloat $ a' * fromInteger b'
    (MyFloat a', MyFloat b') -> MyFloat $ a' * b'

  fromInteger = MyInt
```

As you can see, `abs`, `signum`, and `negate` are identical except for the underlying operation. The same is true of `(+)` and `(*)`. How can I factor out this repetitive logic?

## Attempted Solution

```
myNumberMonoOp :: (a -> a) -> (MyNumber -> MyNumber)
myNumberMonoOp op = \case
  MyInt val -> MyInt $ op val
  MyFloat val -> MyFloat $ op val

myNumberBinOp :: (a -> a -> a) -> (MyNumber -> MyNumber -> MyNumber)
myNumberBinOp op a b = case (a, b) of
    (MyInt a', MyInt b')     -> MyInt $ a' `op` b'
    (MyInt a', MyFloat b')   -> MyFloat $ fromInteger a' `op` b'
    (MyFloat a', MyInt b')   -> MyFloat $ a' `op` fromInteger b'
    (MyFloat a', MyFloat b') -> MyFloat $ a' `op` b'

instance Num MyNumber where
  abs = myNumberMonoOp abs
  signum = myNumberMonoOp signum
  negate = myNumberMonoOp negate
  (+) = myNumberBinOp (+)
  (*) = myNumberBinOp (*)
```

This doesn't type check:

```
/path/to/Main.hs:44:27:error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Integer’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          myNumberMonoOp :: forall a. (a -> a) -> MyNumber -> MyNumber
        at src/Main.hs:42:1-52
    • In the first argument of ‘op’, namely ‘val’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘op val’
      In the expression: MyInt $ op val
    • Relevant bindings include
        op :: a -> a (bound at src/Main.hs:43:16)
        myNumberMonoOp :: (a -> a) -> MyNumber -> MyNumber
          (bound at src/Main.hs:43:1)
   |
44 |   MyInt val -> MyInt $ op val
   |                           ^^^
```

I (think I) understand why this isn't allowed: if it were, `op` may not be defined for `Integer` and `Float`, which would clearly be an issue. But still, I don't see the solution. Is there a way to do this? I'm wondering if I'd need to rewrite my type system in terms of type classes in order to avoid this sort of duplication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution will not work since the `abs` for the `MyInt` and `MyFloat` case are not the same. Indeed, the `abs` for `MyInt` has type `abs :: Int -> Int`, whereas for the `MyFloat` it has type `abs :: Float -> Float`.

You can make a function that works with two functions, one for the `Int`s, and one for the `Float`s:

```
mapNumber :: (Int -> Int) -> (Float -> Float) -> MyNumber -> MyNumber
mapNumber f g = go
  where go (MyInt x) = MyInt (f x)
        go (MyFloat x) = MyFloat (g x)
```

and then implement this as:

```
instance Num MyNumber where
  abs = mapNumber abs abs
  signum = mapNumber signum signum
  negate = mapNumber negate negate
  # …
```

for the two-parameter operations, we do something similar:

```
mapNumber2 :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> (Float -> Float -> Float) -> MyNumber -> MyNumber
mapNumber2 f g = go
  where go (MyInt x) (MyInt y) = MyInt (f x y)
        go x y = g (go' x) (go' y)
        go' (MyInt x) = fromIntegral x
        go' (MyFloat x) = x
```

Another option is to work with a the `RankNTypes` language extension here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

mapNumber :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a) -> MyNumber -> MyNumber
mapNumber f = go
  where go (MyInt x) = MyInt (f x)
        go (MyFloat x) = MyFloat (f x)
```

Then you can implement this with:

```
instance Num MyNumber where
  abs = mapNumber abs
  signum = mapNumber signum
  negate = mapNumber negate
  # …
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with the RankNTypes approach, but it's nice to know there's a way to do it without extensions as well.